# How to get output like this in java using forloop to a text file?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, filewriter

I must get output like this in java

```
     digraph G 
   {
     main -> parse -> execute;
     main -> init;
     main -> cleanup;
     execute -> make_string;
     execute -> printf
     init -> make_string;
     main -> printf;
     execute -> compare;
     }
```

I tried this

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("graph.gv"));

         for(int i=0;i<1;i++)

    {
        System.out.println("digraph G {");

    for (String node : visited)

    {

        System.out.print(node);
        System.out.print("->");
        out.write(node);
        out.flush();

    }
   out.close();

    System.out.println();
    }
      System.out.println("}");
}
```

this is my output

```
      digraph G {
     A->B->E->
     }
     digraph G {
     A->B->D->E->
     }
     digraph G {
     A->B->C->E->
     }
     digraph G {
     A->B->C->D->E->
     }
     digraph G {
     A->D->E->
     }
```

but the output is not printing correctly

Comment: what output you are getting now?

Comment: @PradeepSimha I edited the question and pasted the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
System.out.println("digraph G {");   //  To print it once
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<visited.length()-1; j++)  // Accessing one less node to avoid extra "->" at the end
    for (String node : visited)
    {
        System.out.print(node);
        System.out.print("->");
        out.write(node);
        out.flush();
    }
    System.out.print(node);  //Printing the last node left
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:`System.out.println("digraph G {");` out of the for loop. That is, change this:

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
{
   System.out.println("digraph G {");
   //Your remaining code
}
```

To:

```
System.out.println("digraph G {"); //Notice change here
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
{
   //Your remaining code
}
```

This should work as expected.

Comment: can you post the relevant enhanced forloop to tradtional forloop? I tried your code but still probs persists

Comment: @MuralidharanT, can you please edit the updated code and output?

Answer (score 0):

Use **System.out.format()** method instead of **System.out.println()**

format() can be used if you want to format your output in a certain way.

[Refer to Oracle's tutorial of System.out.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).